# Which Ant version supports OpenJDK 11 and OpenJDK17?

Tags: ant, java-11, java-17, adoptopenjdk

We are moving from IBM JDK 8 to Open JDK 11. Our build is using ANT 1.7.0 currently, and I am getting below error when I build project with OpenJDK 11 using ant 1.7.0

/home/devs/sbx/sand1_7000_db1/perimeter/build.xml:83: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid Constant Pool entry Type 18

Total time: 3 seconds

So, I suppose that due to the incompatibility of ANT with JDK 11. Please help me to know which ANT version supports open JDK 11 and open JDK 17.

Here is what is there in the line 83 of build.xml,

```
<!-- *********************************************************** -->
<!-- Custom Targets                                              -->
<!-- *********************************************************** -->
<target name="checkDependencies" depends="validate">
    <depend srcDir="${clump.root.dir}/product/isolatedSrc:${clump.root.dir}/build/product/classes"
            destdir="${clump.root.dir}/build/product/classes"
            cache="depcache.product"
            closure="yes">
    </depend>
</target>
```

Here is the error in -debug mode,

checkDependencies:
[depend] Adding class info for com.sterlingcommerce.perimeter.VersionInfo

BUILD FAILED
/home/devs/sbx/sand1_7000_db1/perimeter/build.xml:83: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid Constant Pool entry Type 18
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:115)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid Constant Pool entry Type 18
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.constantpool.ConstantPoolEntry.readEntry(ConstantPoolEntry.java:159)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.constantpool.ConstantPool.read(ConstantPool.java:67)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:72)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.AntAnalyzer.determineDependencies(AntAnalyzer.java:91)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.depend.AbstractAnalyzer.getClassDependencies(AbstractAnalyzer.java:99)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.Depend.determineDependencies(Depend.java:344)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.depend.Depend.execute(Depend.java:689)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
... 11 more

Thanks
Dev

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#java-version only mentions a minimum and no maximum. It's possible that the problem is actually some custom task and not ant itself. Can you provide the *whole* output? Also what's on line 83 (and surrounding lines) of your `build.xml`?

Comment: Thanks @JoachimSauer for the quick response, I have added the details u had asked.
So, ant 1.7 itself probably can work work openJDK 11.

Comment: Have added the error details, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception `ClassFormatError: Invalid Constant Pool entry Type 18` occured because the Depend task in the version of Ant you used didn't know how to handle the Invoke Dynamic bytecode instruction. This issue was fixed in Ant 1.9.0:

https://github.com/apache/ant/commit/b103f7e3

You may get other issues with OpenJDK 11/17 though, the best is to simply use the latest version of Ant.